# spinner localization inside a fragment

Tags: android, localization, fragment, spinner

I edited to have the last code I am using with the answer from Krunal. I am still getting crash when I select one of the spinner item that has a listener.

I want the spinner in my fragment to make the user be able to change the language.

However, when the user changes the language the application crashes... So the problem should come from the listener of my spinner. My spinner display effectively the different items

Here is the code:

```
public class GreetingsFragment extends Fragment {

public GreetingsFragment(){}
private Spinner spinner1 ;
Context thiscontext;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    thiscontext = container.getContext();
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_greetings, container, false);

    setSpinnerContent( rootView );

spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> id, View rootView,
                int pos, long arg3) {

                    if (pos == 1) {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                "You have selected Spanish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        setLocale("sp");
                    } else if (pos == 2) {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                "You have selected Japanese", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        setLocale("jp");
                    } else if (pos == 3) {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                "You have selected German", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        setLocale("de");
                    }

                }

         @Override
         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Nothing to select", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

            });


    return rootView;

}

 private void setSpinnerContent( View rootView )
    {
      spinner1 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById( R.id.languages_spinner );
      ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.LANG, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
      adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      spinner1.setAdapter( adapter );
    }


public void setLocale(String lang) {

    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(getActivity(), GreetingsFragment.class);
    refresh.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(refresh);
}

}
```

Comment: I think it is related to this line "Intent refresh = new Intent... But I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Nobody knows what could be leading to the crash ?

Comment: can you share the details of the crash? stack trace, exception message, etc

Comment: Yes sure :) Fragment1 = GreetingsFragment. I updated with the log

Comment: Anyone has any idea ? Would it because of the layout ?

Comment: I still don't see stack trace of crash log or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

as of my knowledge spinner position is start from 0, not a 1,

You are try this one.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if (pos == 0) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "You have selected Spanish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    setLocale("sp");
                } else if (pos == 1) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "You have selected Japanese", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    setLocale("jp");
                } else if (pos == 2) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "You have selected German", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    setLocale("de");
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing to select", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Second thing is that you are trying to convert fragment to activity, so you got this bug,
please try this code, it will resolve your bug.

Comment: About the spinner position I know perfectly about that but the bug is used when I used the 4th one (so "DE").
The fact that I was trying to convert a fragment to activity was indeed the problem I think.
However now that I modified with your code I have "pos" underlined with "pos cannot be resolved to a variable".

Comment: hi, in your code you forget to set spinner adapter,

you have to set spinner adapter, mean add array or list in spinner value.

`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
     spinner.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: hi, the adapter is working fine with the following code, and when clicking on the spinner I got the array I need.
The crash occurs when clicking on one of the spinner item that have a listener that is why I think it is related to my 2 previous comments.

Comment: The "list" is done through adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);